# How to improve classification of small texts

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

The data that I've got are mostly tweets or small comments (300-400 chars). I used a Bag-Of-Word model and used NaiveBayes classification. Now I'm having a lot of misclassified cases which are of the type mentioned below :-

```
1.] He sucked on a lemon early morning to get rid of hangover.
2.] That movie sucked big time.
```

Now the problem is that during sentiment classification both are getting "Negative" just because of the word "sucked"

```
Sentiment Classification : 1.] Negative 2.] Negative
```

Similarly during document classification both are getting classified into "movies" due to the presence of word "sucked".

```
Document classification  : 1.] Movie    2.] Movie
```

This is just one of such instances, I'm facing a huge number of wrong classifications and don't have any idea on how to improve the accuracy.

Comment: Using an n-gram model might make your system more complex and will require more training data, but it will help to get rid of cases like the example you gave -- the "suck on" (after stemming) 2-gram should not be associated with a negative connotation.

Answer (score 3):

(1)
One straightforward possible change from Bag-of-Words with Naive Bayes is to generate polynomial combinations of Bag-of-Words features. It might solve the problems you have shown above.

> "sucked" + "lemon" (positive)
>
> "sucked" + "movie" (negative)

Of course, you can also generate polynomial combinations of n-grams but the number of features might be too large.

The scikit-learn library prepares a preprocessing class for the purpose.

sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)

Theoretically, SVM with the polynomial kernel does the same thing as PolynomialFeatures + linear SVM but slightly different regarding how you store the model information.

In my experience, PolynomialFeatures + linear SVM performs reasonably well for short text classification including sentiment analysis.

If the dataset size is not large enough, the training dataset might not contain "sucked" + "lemon". In the case, dimensionality reduction such as Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) and topic models such as Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) are suitable tools to semantic clusters for words.

(2)
Another direction is to utilize more sophisticated natural language processing (NLP) techniques to extract additional information from short texts. For example, Part-of-Speech (POS) tagging, Named Entity Recognition (NER) will give more information than plain BoWs. A python library for NLP called Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) implements those functions.

(3)
You can also take slow but steady way. Analyzing errors in prediction by the current model to design new hand-crafted features is a promising way to improve the accuracy of the model.

There is a library for short-text classification called LibShortText, which also contains an error analysis function and preprocessing functions such as TF-IDF weighting. It might help you to learn how to improve the model via error analysis.

LibShortText ([https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libshorttext/))

(4)
For further information, take a look at the literature on sentiment analysis of Tweets will give you more advanced information.

Comment: How does one combine BOW with NER+POS as feature representation. Any tutorial references on that ?

Comment: Just add features extracted from NER (e.g., Bag-of-NER) and POS (e.g., POS n-gram) information to create a new feature set will do. Non-linear classifiers can take into account the combination or you can directly create the combinatorial features. You can find the techniques in some NLP papers but I do not know any good tutorials for that.

Comment: How does one represent Bag-of-NER+ POS-ngram as features ? For instance ---> [('Starbucks', 'NNS'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('not', 'RB'), ('doing', 'VBG'), ('very', 'RB'), ('well', 'RB'), ('lately', 'RB')]. Can you please help me with Bag-of-NER+ POS-ngram for this sentence.

Comment: POS n-gram means just n-gram of POS tags not tokens. So, POS bi-gram will extract features `BOS-NNS:1, NNS-VBZ:1, VBZ-RB:1, RB-VBG:1, VBG-RB:1, RB-RB:2, RB-EOS:1` from the example. For Bag-of-NE, I just meant that NE has something about the context of a sentence. Let's say the NE of starbucks is `<ORGanization>`, then `NE=RG:1` will be the active feature. The feature set expanded by Bag-of-NE is the number of NE classes that ared used by the NER classifier.

Comment: Ok so for the example sentence, the feature vector becomes = [BOS-NNS:1, NNS-VBZ:1, VBZ-RB:1, RB-VBG:1, VBG-RB:1, RB-RB:2, RB-EOS:1, NE=RG:1]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use a more powerful classifier like [Support Vector Machines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html). Also depending on the amount of data you have, you could try deep learning with convolutional neural nets. For this you will need a huge number of training examples (100k-1M).

Comment: Ive very small amount of data only 70K to 100k(max). I dont think DL's gonna help me then. What kind of features shall I feed the SVM to take care of such misclassifications?